# CSS3 Step Animation - Not changing Image, Just Moving Image

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to use a CSS3 Step Animation to change from one image to another using a simple 2 image sprite sheet. I can't seem to get the second image to load in place of the first image. I have looked at other examples and I really can't see where I am going wrong. So if anyone could help it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/wcLzb)

```
<div class="character">
  <div class="beak"></div>
</div>

@keyframes newquestion-beak {
   from { background-position:    0px 0; }
     to { background-position: -100px 0; }
}

.character > div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.character .beak {
  background-image: url(http://s22.postimg.org/6mb37v5sh/compiled_beaks.png);
  animation: newquestion-beak .8s steps(2) infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your background positioning wasn't right. Try:

```
@keyframes newquestion-beak {
   from { background-position: -100px 0; }
     to { background-position:  100px 0; }
}
```

<kbd>[Running demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/skeurentjes/pen/coHLk)</kbd>

Comment: I can't understand how that works? Beacause if I put background-position: 100px 0; in the css it does not show anything

Comment: http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/xfIol This is my full version using a huge sprite sheet, as you can see I need to understand how this works in order to be able to use the animations

Answer (score 0):

Using "steps(2)" in the animation seems to only move the image halfway. Doubling the 'to' background-position works for me, using Chrome.

[Demo with change.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zDyop)

Comment: Same comment as below - If i put background-position: -200px 0; in the css it does not show anything. Any idea what is going on with these step animations?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not show anything? No animation at all?

Comment: Sorry I mean if I don't set an animation and just set the background-position with the same value then it shows nothing. It looks like with the step animation you have to put the background position after the last one that you want to use.

Comment: Maybe old... but did anyone find out whats the thing with the Step animation? keeping steps(2) doesn't give the Full 2 steps :( ! ?